# Программа русификатор (поиск)

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Подскажите программу с помощью которой можно русифицировать файлы (.dll и .exe)

К примеру файлы от программы VMware-workstation-full-12.5.9-7535481

Но, чтобы программа была не обычной, которая распознается на VirusTotal (может есть способы редактировать эти файлы в Visual Studio или подобных)

p.s. по тегам не определился...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Раньше, для "русификации" некоторых приложений активно использовался редактор ресурсов [Restorator](https://www.bome.com/products/restorator). Но про его отношения с антивирусами ничего не знаю.

Comment: Сейчас такие и подобные программы распознаются как компиляторы вирусов, т.е. программа оставляет свой след в файле и антивирусным компаниям проще распознать все файлы собранные внутри таких программ, чем определять каждый файл. Поэтому нужна возможность отредактировать в более известном софте с возможностью подписывать файлы своей лицензией (если только сами файлы не защищены разработчиком).